# Google Maps won't work when API key is provided / This page was unable to display a Google maps element

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, api-key

I've been using google maps API V3 for a while now and it was working fine. Yesterday i tried adding Static Maps API to my application and i encountered an error where the image was either not displayed at all or i get an error saying 'InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedMapError' which tells me something must be wrong with the api key i've been using, but i use the same key with other scripts in my application and they worked fine. I double-checked with developer's console and made sure the Static Maps API is activated and the key is correct. Then i removed the api key from the static image link request and it worked, but i noticed all my other scripts, using this key stopped working displaying these errors:

`This page was unable to display Google Maps Element`

and the console says:

`UrlAuthenticationCommonError: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#errorcodes` .
Regenerating the api key didn't work. Removing the key or using a key from a different account with the same settings in developer's console solves the problem, but i need it to be under this account for billing purposes

> **TLDR;** My application suddenly works only without API key or with a key from another google developer account with the exact same settings. What
>   may be causing the problem with this particular account?

Comment: Did you set up your key using the link provided [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/intro#api_key)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it was some bug with my account. I disabled and deleted all APIs and keys, re-enabled and re-created them and the problem was fixed.

Comment: sounds like a refreshment of Googles API cache issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed,

In the console say to add a link in this format:

> *.example.com/*

I changed to this:

> *example.com/*

And it worked!